# coverage panel not showing information (in android studio)

Tags: android-studio, testing, code-coverage, test-coverage

I'm trying to run a test with coverage (using the command [image: Run with Coverage - icon] **Run 'GameViewModelTest' with Coverage**), but when I do that and then open the Coverage panel (after the Build is complete), no information appears in the panel, and it just says "Nothing to show" with a gray background.

[image: Coverage panel - "Nothing to show" with a gray background]

Do you have any clues as to why this isn't working and how I can make it work?

Comment: Any update on this @cmd770?

Comment: So far no update.